# How can I solve this problem based on array in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting this error:
Attempt to read property"id" on array
File name: controler/patient.php
Line 352

I had just modified by putting the entire code for further clarification
This is the code:

```
$username = $this->input->post('name');

            if (empty($id)) {     // Adding New Patient
                if ($this->ion_auth->email_check($email)) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Cette adresse email est déjà enregistré dans la base données');
                    redirect('patient/addNewView');
                } else {
                    $dfg = 5;
                    $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $dfg);
//                    $ion_user_id=this->db-get_where('users', array('email'=> $email))->row()['id'];
//                    $ion_user_id = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email))->row()['id'];
                    $ion_user_id = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email))->row()->id;
                    if ($ion_user_id) {
                        $ion_user_id = $ion_user_id->row()->id;
                    }
                    $this->patient_model->insertPatient($data);
                    $patient_user_id = $this->db->get_where('pa;tient', array('email' => $email))->row()->id;
                    $id_info = array('ion_user_id' => $ion_user_id);
                    $this->patient_model->updatePatient($patient_user_id, $id_info);
                    $this->hospital_model->addHospitalIdToIonUser($ion_user_id, $this->hospital_id);

                    if (!empty($sms)) {
                        $this->sms->sendSmsDuringPatientRegistration($patient_user_id);
                    }


                    $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Ajouté');
                }
                //    }
            } else { // Updating Patient
                $ion_user_id = $this->db->get_where('patient', array('id' => $id))->row()->ion_user_id;
                if (empty($password)) {
                    $password = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $ion_user_id))->row()->password;
                } else {
                    $password = $this->ion_auth_model->hash_password($password);
                }
                $this->patient_model->updateIonUser($username, $email, $password, $ion_user_id);
                $this->patient_model->updatePatient($id, $data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Modifié');
            }
            // Loading View
            if (!empty($redirect)) {
                redirect('finance/addPaymentView');
            } else {
                redirect('patient');
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to know how can I solve that

Comment: which is line 352?

Comment: The code seems to have invalid syntax - perhaps a copy/paste error?

Comment: @ADyson the last line is

Comment: row() must return an array, then. Try row()["id"]

Comment: 1) This code has errors, so couldn 't run, 2) You need to see why your users table does not contain the email.

Comment: @Forbs See no evidence from the error message quoted that the users table wouldn't contain the email. It does seem to return array when row() is called. The issue is that the OP is trying to access that array like it's an object. I'm unclear where the logic for your second point in your comment came from? I don't disagree there is a syntax error - but I'd guess that's a typo when the OP was trying to move their code here (for some reason some people seem to re-type it instead of pasting, which I never understand, but there you go).

Comment: @ADyson I've done it but there is an other error: **Undefined array key "id"**

Comment: OK well then obviously the array doesn't have an entry named "id".  What did you expect that code to do, and why did you expect it? And what are you trying to achieve with it? You should probably also debug it and find out what the array returned by row() _does_ contain

Comment: @ADyson This is a form for registering elements in the database and when I save, it gives me these errors

Comment: The bit giving you the error is when you try to fetch data from the database, not save into it. What is the purpose of that specific line, within your application? And again, you should debug what the array returned by row() actually contains

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing the issue on the following line :

```
$ion_user_id=this->db-get_where('users', array('email'=> $email))->row()->id;
```

than firstly confirm that you are getting "row()" as not empty and hence after validating this one as not empty than check you are getting "row()" as "stdObject", if it's stdObject than it's fine if it's not object than try as

```
$ion_user_id=this->db-get_where('users', array('email'=> $email))->row()['id'];
```

Comment: @M. Mad I've done it but it gives me one other error like this: **Undefined array key "id"**

Answer (score 0):

plz mention the full code with error so that anyone can understand the problem and can answer
as of my knowledge what are you want to access in first line of your code is **id** is constant if not then it will be mostly variable if variable then use **$id**
so first modify the first line of code from

```
if(empty(id)){
```

to

```
if(empty($id)){
```

if you are facing error in last line
then first check **$ion_user_id** like this because if you don't get any result then it return false

```
$ion_user_id=$this->db-get_where('users', array('email'=> $email))->row()->id;
if($ion_user_id){
 $ion_user_id=$ion_user_id->row()->id;
}
```

Comment: #Md Aziz let me make the full code because the error persists